# function does not add value

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I have a function that should dynamically add a value to an input box.

```
function setValue(value, elementId){
  //alert(value);
  //alert(elementId);
  jQuery(elementId).attr("value", value);
  //cleanFrame();
}
```

I have the following input `<input id="inputTest" />` and the function is called with this link, `<a href="#" onclick="Javascript:parent.setValue('Testing','inputTest')">Click Me</a>`

What I am expecting to happen is for the input to become `<input id="inputTest" value="testing"/>`. Sadly, nothing happens when I run my function.

Comment: You may want jQuery's [`val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2).

Comment: Think about what you are passing to `jQuery`: `jQuery('inputTest')`. Does that look right to you? Which elements would that select?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your jquery call should be

```
jQuery('#' + elementId).val(value);
```

Comment: While `val` should likely be used in this case, the problem is ultimately just the invalid selector.